# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError - Native method not found

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use JNI in Android but keep getting 'UnsatisfiedLinkError - Native method not found'. I've spent some hours searching for solutions, but still having trouble. Thanks for any help.

My code is as follows:

Java class:

```
package com.example.icam;

public class Native {
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("nativeLib");
    }
    public static native int nativeFunction();
}
```

Header file (generated using javah):

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_icam_Native */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_icam_Native
#define _Included_com_example_icam_Native
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_example_icam_Native
 * Method:    nativeFunction
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_icam_Native_nativeFunction
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C++ source file:

```
#include "com_example_icam_Native.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_icam_Native_nativeFunction(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz){
    return (jint)1;
}
```

My Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := native.cpp

include C:\OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE     := nativeLib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm very new to JNI, maybe I'm missing something?

Error message:

```
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.icam.Native.nativeFunction:()I
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at com.example.icam.Native.nativeFunction(Native Method)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at com.example.icam.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-14 03:44:37.501: E/AndroidRuntime(23484):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Now that you've edited part of the error out of your question, please post the entire message you got with the exception.

Comment: You should confirm that the symbol is present in your .so file, and the right .so file is on your device.  Run `arm-linux-androideabi-nm -D nativeLib.so` (where the nm binary lives somewhere under the NDK "toolchains" directory, and `nativeLib.so` is the library extracted from your device with `adb pull`) to see the symbol table.  Also look above the exception in the logcat output to see if the VM is saying anything interesting.

Comment: I ran the above, and the symbol was indeed present. The code actually works now, I'm not exactly sure what I did. Now I just gotta start writing my actual C++ neon-enabled code :)

Comment: You've edited this so many times it is impossible for anybody to know what the actual problem was. This question should be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The function declared in your .c file isn't the function declared in your .h file, or as the native method in your Java code either. You've changed the name somewhere along the line without keeping everything in sync.

Comment: It was a bit silly of me, but that doesn't fix the issue (I've updated the description). I decided to change the method names etc. declarations to see if something would work (hence typo). I tried not using a header file (but keeping the jni.h include in source file), but doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Re your edit, you still don't have the same calling sequences in the .h file and the .c file. Please post the entire exception message. I don't know why you thought not using a header file would be a good idea. It isn't.

Comment: I saw some examples (e.g. in Android NDK which weren't using a header file). I have added the error message in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: You still have the wrong calling sequence. Look again. The .c file must agree 100% with the .h file, and the .h file must be exactly as generated by `javah.` NB You don't need `extern "C"` in the .c file. Including the .h file does that for you.

Comment: I've made sure all parameter types are the same and removed the extern "C", but the same error is there. I've edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: If what's in your post == your current code you still have `nativeIsNeon.` If it isn't, please update your post to everything current.

Comment: The function signatures match. 'nativeIsNeon' is not there, as shown by the code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I fixed it by changing

> JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_icam_Native_nativeFunction
>     (JNIEnv *, **jclass**);
>
> to
>
> JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_icam_Native_nativeFunction
>     (JNIEnv *, **jobject**);

Comment: the reason is  public **static** native int nativeFunction();

Comment: This is an answer, it was not obvious because of the awkward phrasing.

Answer (score -2):

You have to again build your **.so** file by **ndk_build**